# Need SQL Query for this scenario

Tags: sql

Table structure:

```
ProjectID ParentID  Name        Path
   38          2    client      |2|38|
  108         38    Sample1     |2|38|108
  205         38    Sample2     |2|38|205
  206         38    Sample3     |2|38|206
  207         38    Sample4     |2|38|207
```

Query:

```
SELECT Name, ProjectId
  FROM dbo.Projects project
 WHERE ParentID = 38
```

This would give me all the rows from the above table except the first row.

However I want to achieve the following!

```
ProjectID   ParentID    Name           Path
   108         38        clientSample1  |2|38|108
   205         38        clientSample2  |2|38|205
   206         38        clientSample3  |2|38|206
   207         38        clientSample4  |2|38|207
```

SQL experts please let me know the query on how to achieve this. I appreciate your input.

PN: Sorry about the table structure. I couldn't paste any images yet.

Comment: #1 - You should wrap your database information in code tags, it makes it easier to read.  #2 - Do you just want the row information for ParentID 38, with 'client' added to the name?

Comment: I question storing the path - you're breating the Don't Repeat Yourself pattern, and introducing the possibility that the inheritance view from project -> parent doesn't concur with the stored "path".

Comment: I will keep code tags in mind. Thanks! This is a table structure that cames with a third party tool which is a closed box.I didn't like the path column either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and you simply want 'client' in front of the name:

```
SELECT P1.ProjectId, P1.ParentId, P2.[Name] + P1.[Name], P1.Path
FROM Projects P1
INNER JOIN Projects P2 ON P1.ParentId = P2.ProjectId
Where P1.ParentId = 38
```

Effectively, you're joining the Projects table onto itself a second time, to find out the parent's name.  From there, you can concatenate the two names together.

Answer (score 0):

The first row has a `ParentID = 2`, your query explicitly ask for `ParentID = 38`

try:

`SELECT Name, ProjectId FROM dbo.Projects project WHERE (ParentID = 38 OR ProjectId = 38)`

Answer (score 0):

Try below two

```
SELECT ProjectId,parentid, 'Client'+[name],path 
FROM Project 
WHERE parentid=38
```

or

```
DECLARE @String varchar(10)
SET @string=(SELECT name FROM Project WHERE parentid=2)
SELECT ProjectId,parentid,@string+name,path 
FROM Project WHERE parentid=38
```